# Expectation on 1/X

Tags: probability

In general can one say that for a random variable X:

$E[\frac{1}{X}] = \frac{1}{E[X]}$ ?

I've worked out a few examples where this works but I'm not sure how widely this is useful...

Comment: In general, $1/E[X]$ is the inverse of an arithmetic mean, and $E[1/X]$ is the inverse of a harmonic mean. Arithmetic and harmonic means of the same set are highly unlikely to be equal to each other...

Comment: If $X$ is a positive random variable, then this equality holds if and only if $X$ is a constant (that is, $X=c$ almost surely).

Comment: *I've worked out a few examples where this works*... Really? Which ones?

Comment: An example where this *does* hold is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2312238/321264). Further discussion can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/305713/119261).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is very rarely true. Let's do a random example. Let $X$ be uniform on $[1,3]$. Then $E(X)=2$. But
$$E\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)=\int_1^3 \frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\,dx=\frac{\log 3}{2}\ne \frac{1}{2}.$$

For a simpler example, let $X=1$ with probability $1/2$, and let $X=3$ with probability $1/2$. Then $E(X)=2$.

But $E(1/X)=(1/2)(1)+(1/2)(1/3)=2/3$.

Comment: I am somewhat confused with this answer. Isn't $E(1/X) = \int_{1}^{3} 1/x \cdot f(1/x) d(1/x)$, where $f$ is the density function of the random variable $1/x$, and is this the same as the term given in the answer?

Comment: @Florian that would be incorrect since it is implicit here that the expectation is over the random variable $X$ not it’s inverse. The density would accordingly have be of $X$.

Answer (score 17):

Jensen's inequality for functions of RVs is $\mathbf{E} \varphi(x) \geq \varphi(\mathbf{E}X)$ when $\varphi$ is convex and $\mathbf{E} \varphi(x) \leq \varphi(\mathbf{E}X)$ for concave functions. Clearly $Y = \frac{1}{X}$ is a convex function when restricted to the positive reals or the negative reals, so
${\bf E}[X^{-1}]\ge {\bf E}[X]^{-1}$ is true as long as $X$ is almost surely positive or almost surely negative.

Comment: There is a "for concave functions" missing.

Comment: The function $x\mapsto 1/x$ is only convex on the domains $(0,+\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0)$. Therefore, the inequality $E[1/X]\ge 1/E[X]$ is only valid if $P(X> 0)=1$ or $P(X<0)=1$. For example, if $P(X=1)=2/3$ and $P(X=-1)=1/3$, then $E[1/X]=1/2$, while $1/E[X]=2$.

Answer (score 7):

For such a case, it is a good idea to study [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Another counterexample to the one given by André Nicolas is this one. Consider $X$ to be a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance one. Then $E[X]=\mu$ but not only is $E[\frac{1}{X}]$ not in general equal to $1/\mu$; rather, it does not exist.

Comment: How do I see that it doesn't exist? Could you explain that? Thank you!

Comment: I think you'd need to compute the inner product of f(x) and 1/x (as per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition)), which in this case (Wolfram Alpha notation ignoring constants, m=1: Integrate[exp(-(x-1)^2)/x,{x,-inf,inf}] ) just doesn't converge. Why? Well, I guess the area under the curve is just infinite. I remember [Infinite Acres](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_c06ANw288) from calc, but beyond that you'd have to do some [tests](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ImproperIntegralsCompTest.aspx) to really check.

Answer (score 0):

Take any continuous random variable $X$ with density $f_X$ and support on an open interval containing the origin. If $f_X(0)>0$, then $\mathsf EX^{-1}$ does not exist; however, there are many density functions that satisfy these properties and $\mathsf EX$ is finite and nonzero, e.g. $X\sim\mathcal N(1,1)$. Hence, $\mathsf EX^{-1}\neq (\mathsf EX)^{-1}$ under these conditions.

Answer (score -2):

In general if, X>0 , then the following inequality always will be satisfied:

```
E(1/X)>= 1/E(X)
```

Answer (score -3):

Y = 1/X is a convex function when x > 0

Comment: Alex already wrote that.