# One over a Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If X is a normal distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$ is $\frac{1}{X}$ any sort of "official" distribution or something that should just be computed?

In particular I'm looking to find the expectation $E[\frac{1}{X}]$ where X is a Brownian motion.

Comment: It has a name (Recinormal Distribution!) and comes up in some applications.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I filled in your rain example comment. So it did not go to waste. Even though it it gone forever.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  Interesting.  Can it have a finite mean and variance?

Comment: @Dirk Are you reading the answers to your questions?

Comment: @did I am I was just wondering if there was some exceptional cases involving this Recinormal Distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I answered to your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/248472/48763), $E[1/X]=\infty$ for a normal distribution.