# Is it true in general that $E(1/X) = 1/E(X)$?

Tags: probability, expectation

This concerns a discrete random variable $X$. I assume the relation doesn't hold in general, but I would like to prove this.

I have tried to use the property that 
$$
E(g(X)) = \sum_x g(x)f(x) 
$$
and then simply write
$$
\sum_x \frac{1}{x}P(X=x) = \frac{1}{\sum_x x P(X=x)}
$$ 
and then play around with this algebraically without any success.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut what is wrong?

Comment: $$\sum \frac{1}{x}p\{X=x\}=p\{X=1\}+\frac{p\{X=2\}}{2}+\frac{p\{X=3\}}{3}+...$$ and $$\frac{1}{\sum xp\{X=x\}}=\frac{1}{p\{X=1\}+2p\{X=2\}+3p\{X=3\}+4p\{X=4\}+...}$$

Comment: Sorry, it was rather short. You argument is correct, and you obviously **don't have**, in general, $\frac{1}{\sum_k x_k p_k}=\sum_k \frac{1}{x_k}p_k$. You can easily find counterexamples.

Comment: I guess I was looking for some expression showing **when** it holds but fair enough. Badly posed question :)

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305713/constructing-example-showing-mathbbe-left-frac1x-right-frac1-mathb) thread on CV is also relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expectation on 1/X](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248472/expectation-on-1-x)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let X be the discrete distribution which takes values 1 and 2 with equal probability.  Then $E (X)=\frac32 $ but $ E (\frac1x) = \frac34 $.

(Almost *any* distribution you choose, discrete or continuous, will confirm that $E(\frac1X)\ne\frac1{E(X)}$.  The underlying reason is that $\frac 1a + \frac1b \ne \frac1{a+b}$.)

Comment: Sorry but the "underlying reason" seems more akin to something like $$\frac12\left(\frac1a+\frac1b\right)\ne\frac1{\frac12(a+b)}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Counter-example 1: If $X \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$, then $\mathrm{E}(X)=np$, but $\mathrm{E}(1/X)$ is not even well defined: $k=0, \, 1/k=?$.

Counter-example 2: If $X \sim \text{Bin(n,p)}$, then $\mathrm{E}(X+1)=np+1$, 
$$
\mathrm{E}\left( \frac{1}{X+1}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}=\frac{1}{n+1}\neq\frac{1}{np+1}=\frac{1}{\mathrm{E}(X+1)}.
$$

Comment: how about a well defined example when it is not true? o/w I can just add at the end of the statement: whenever both expressions are defined

Comment: @BCLC See my edit.

Comment: Except ${\rm E}\left(\frac{1}{X+1}\right) = \frac{1-(1-p)^{n+1}}{p(n+1)}$

Answer (score 4):

Another way to see that it is not true, is that for any positive random variable $X$ with $\mathbb E [X] \neq 0$,
$$
\frac{1}{\mathbb E[X]} < \mathbb E\left[\frac{1}{X} \right] 
$$
by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form) and the fact that $f(x) = 1/x$ is strictly convex in $\mathbb R^+$

Comment: It would be good to mention that the inequality here is strict since 1/x is strictly convex.

Comment: For non-constant X.

Comment: $E(1/X) = 1/E(X)$ when $X$ is a constant with probability $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a discrete $X$ which takes value $-2$ or $2$, both with probability $\tfrac 12$.
What is $1/X$ then?
And what are $E$ of the two...?