# Let $X$ be a continuos r.v and X > 0 is this true? $\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{X}) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(X)}$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuos r.v and X > 0 is this true?
$\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{X}) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(X)}$

Comment: No... Try to come up with some counter-examples for yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true in general that $E(1/X) = 1/E(X)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910846/is-it-true-in-general-that-e1-x-1-ex)

Comment: As an explicit example, take $X ( x)=x$ on the interval $[1,2]$, with uniform distribution $dx$ .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expectation on 1/X](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248472/expectation-on-1-x)

Answer (score 3):

Not in general:

$E\left(x\right)\:=\:\sum _{i=1}^n\:\left(x_i\cdot p_i\right)$

$E\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\:=\:\sum _{i=1}^n\:\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\cdot p_i\right)$

Now, what happens when you plug numbers into that?
Say X = {1,2,3,4} and p = {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4}. Then:
E(X) = 2.5 whilst E(1/X) = 25/48.

However, that ws a mistake for omitting the key to the question: CONTINUOUS RV. Thus:

$E\left(x\right)=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\left(x\cdot f\left(x\right)\right)\:dx;\:E\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\int _{-\infty \:}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{x}\cdot \:f\left(x\right)\right)\:dx$

The intuition is retained from above. Most any other example will prove that E(x) doesn't equal E(1/x), except (maybe) for a some coincidences that may appear here and there.

Comment: the op did say 'continuous' - not that it should matter!

Comment: Major minor detail. Thanks